# How could detect if client close the connection on rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an API application on Rails 4.2.0. Wonder if there any way I could tell if the client closes the connection after they made API call to the server.

Tried session and cookie, seems they do not design for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed the connection" ?  Isn't the user just making regular HTTP requests?

Comment: for example, people hard-reload page and close the window. The request has been submitted to the server and line up to wait for execute at server side. After quest finished, server-side will return 200 but meanwhile people already walk away, there is no receiver anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment on what you are actually trying to do, the only way I can think of would be via javascript using `onunload`.  Here is a very basic example.

```
<body onunload="handleOnClose()">
  <script>
  function handleOnClose()
  {
      // send something to your backend 
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

For more info see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Comment: Don't know this before. let me try, might work for my case. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every HTTP requests ends up being closed when it's complete, as that's how the HTTP request-response cycle works. It's extremely rare to have connections hanging open as long-polling fell out of style once WebSocket was standardized.

After the client has made a call you can assume that request has completed and they've disconnected. There's no way of knowing if they will make additional requests or not, it's entirely up to the client.